# Validating an alphanumeric code in php and using it in an SQL statement

Tags: php, sql

I'm trying to validate an alphanumeric code from a table that is 4 characters long, the first character being a letter and the last three any combination of numbers for a member ID.
Once the member ID is verified I need to use that value in an SQL command to get that member and its information into a table.

```
            $memberid = 0;
            $memberid = (int) $_GET['memberid'];
            if ($memberid > 0) {
                require_once('dbtest.php');
                $query = "SELECT * FROM tblMembers WHERE MemID = '$memberid' ";
```

This initially did the same process with just a numeric ID, so the rest is already completed, I just need help with making it recognize alphanumeric ID's, I appreciate the help.

Answer (score 0):

Use a regular expression:

```
if (preg_match('/^[a-z]\d{3}$/i', $_GET['memberid'])) {
    require_once('dbtest.php');
    $stmt = $conn->prepare("SELECT * FROM tblMembers WHERE MemID = ?");
    $stmt->bind_param("s", $_GET['memberid']);
    $stmt->execute();
    $result = $stmt->get_result();
    $row = $result->fetch_assoc();
}
```